# Unable to achieve expected parsing output with strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I have been working on this for a while now but I do not seem to be able to resolve this bug. Any insights will be greatly appreciated thanks.

I am writing code that will parse a string first by ";" and then by " ". The code I have below is as follows:

```
void arrayVis(char **arr, int size){
  printf("[");
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
  if(arr[i] == NULL || strcmp(arr[i], "") == 0){
  break;
  }
  printf("%s,", arr[i]);
}

void parser2(char *line){
  char *token = strtok(line, " ");
  char *arr[10];
  int index = 0;
  while(token != NULL){
    arr[index] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    index++;
  }
  arrayVis(arr, 10);
}

void parser1(char *line){
  char *token = strtok(line, ";");
  while(token != NULL){
    parser2(token);
    // myPrint(token);
    printf("\n");
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
  }
}
```

array vis will just allow me to visualize the array that is produced. When I pass "1 2 3;4 5 6;"
I am expecting an output of

```
[1,2,3
[4,5,6
```

but instead I just get the output

```
[1,2,3
```

Why is my output omitting the second portion of the parse? I have been thinking about this for a while now but I dont seem to understand why this happens. Any insights will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is not *reentrant*, as it keeps internal state. You can't use it nested.

Comment: strtok uses static pointer to save the position. So you first have to parse by ';' and THEN in another loop parse by ' '. lookup how strtok with NULL works

Comment: The function `arrayVis` misses the last `}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void) {
    static const char *ROW_TOKENS=";";
    static const char *COL_TOKENS=" ";
    char buf[] = "data1;data2 data3;data4 data5";
    char *aux_row,*cursor_row;

    cursor_row = strtok_r(buf, ROW_TOKENS, &aux_row);
    // printf("[A] buf: %p, cursor_row=%p, aux_row=%p\n", buf, cursor_row, aux_row);

    while (cursor_row) {
        char *aux_col,*cursor_col;

        printf("[");

        cursor_col = strtok_r(cursor_row, COL_TOKENS, &aux_col);
        // printf("[B] cursor_row=%p, aux_row=%p, cursor_col=%p, aux_col=%p\n",
        //        cursor_row, aux_row, cursor_col, aux_col);

        while (cursor_col) {
            // printf("[C] cursor_row=%p, aux_row=%p, cursor_col=%p, aux_col=%p\n",
            //        cursor_row, aux_row, cursor_col, aux_col);

            printf("%s,", cursor_col);
            cursor_col = strtok_r(NULL, COL_TOKENS, &aux_col);
        }

        cursor_row = strtok_r(NULL, ROW_TOKENS, &aux_row);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```